# Direct limits of completely positive maps on $C^*$-algebras vs. operator systems

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, operator-algebras

I believe I've heard, as part of the "lore," that the category (operator systems, completely positive maps) has direct limits, whereas the category ($C^*$-algebras, completely positive maps) does not.  Or perhaps one had to tweak the morphisms by specifying "unital" or "contractive".  I would appreciate either

- a reference that discusses direct limits of completely positive maps on some category or other, or
- an example (if indeed one exists) of a direct system of ($C^*$-algebras, CP maps) where the limit object is not a $C^*$-algebra?  My best guess would be to iterate a CP map from some $A$ to itself, but I don't really know what the limit would look like.

Comment: If you want to talk cp maps, I guess you'll have to stay within operator systems, rather than operator spaces.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that!  Edited appropriately.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled about your question, as the image of a C$^*$-algebra through a CP map is not necessarily a C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it is.  So there do exist inductive systems of CP maps between $C^*$-algebras.  If you take the limit of such a system in the category of operator spaces, you will get an operator space that may or may not be a $C^*$-algebra, so that the limit might not exist with the category of CP maps between $C^*$-algebras.  Or at least I think that's what I've been told...I'm looking to pin down the details.